# dynamic updated multiple select combobox in jsp when values change

Tags: html, sql, jsp, web, event-handling

I have a web page that looks like this:
[image]

the services are stored in a database table with its associated functions... so for each service there is a set of functions associated with it like this:

[image]

the database table snapshot shows the set of functions associated with the BatchItemService only, but all other services have their own functions...

what I want to do is to set the function multiple select as invisible and set it to visible after selecting the service name from the services combobox, in addition, I want the function combobox be populated with the function names associated with the service name selected only.. there is also one more thing, the user can select multiple services.. I'm using jsp with mysql database.
HELP please, thank you!

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSP or MySQL since those are server-side components. Your problem is on the client side. If you are asking for tools javascript and jQuery are my suggestions. But there's a lot more to learn to fool around that.

Comment: thanks for your reply .. currently I was thinking of lots of options and I had an idea to call javascript class from the HTML select then the javascript function will call a jsp function to pull the data for the combobox from the table .. not sure if its a good idea though!!

Comment: Well, you don't call a javascript class, but a javascript method. But that's the ideia, you make an AJAX call to a JSP servlet, passing some paramethers, do whatcha have to do and then, if necessary respond the request to your client.